# Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object Heap, even though i have more than 10000MB available

Tags: java, memory, windows-7, heap-memory, ram

I have **java options** set to **-Xms1024M** inside environment variables. I am using windows 7 as the operating system. However if i try to run any java program i get error **Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object Heap**

I checked my **RAM usage** and i see that there is plenty of memory available.
Resource monitor shows below stats:

**Hardware reserved:207 MB
In Use:5855 MB
Modified:44 MB
Standby:7849 MB
Free:2276 MB**

---

**Available:10139 MB
Cached:7908 MB
Total:16177 MB
Installed: 16384 MB**

Can anyone help how this can be resolved and explain how exactly allocation works with respect to RAM. I believe that as memory is available, there should be some way to allocated it

Comment: Which java version are you using 32 bit or 64 bit? Also, let me know your RAM size.

Comment: One more point, I can see you have used  -Xms. Xms specifies the initial memory allocation pool. Please use -Xmx. Please follow below link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms

Comment: Iam using java 1.8

Comment: Have you tried with -Xmx instead of -Xms? Run -XMx with more than 1024M since 1024M=1024000KB and looks like you application need more than 1024000KB .

Comment: I have tried with xmx too

Comment: I hope you have used first 'X' in uppercase. Are you getting the same error ?  Have you tried with increasing the heap size for instance 1024M to 2048M ?

Comment: Yes I used X and tried all 1024, 2048.. I was only successful for 512

Comment: Great so it is working now. If my comments helped you let me know if I can add it in answer. You can accept it so It will allow other users to see it.